# how to retrieve url on third line of response as drawn, using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when I want to parse the response from the server as shown below, can anyone help me to solve this problem

How to retrieve URL on third line of response as drawn, using flutter?

[image]

#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,METRO TV
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3

Comment: Hi, can you paste the response's raw text so it can be easily copied?

Comment: ``LineSplitter.split(text).toList()[2]`` should return the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Simply use (alternate solution):

```
print(text.split('\n')[2]); // http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3
```

You can achieve this by using the [split](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-convert/LineSplitter/split.html) method offered by the [LineSplittere](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html) class which returns a list of lines.

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {

  String text = '''#EXTM3U
  #EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="", METRO TV
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3''';
  
  print(LineSplitter.split(text).toList()[2]);
  
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3
```

Comment: thanks for solution
what if the case is like this?


#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,METRO TV http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,TVONE http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/5

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,TVRI http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/33

see here new case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72360628/how-to-convert-this-response-to-playlist

Answer (score 0):

First get response in the `String` data type.

Now you can do it by extract all urls from whole string response to the list and get last item from that list.

Get list of URLs:

```
final urlRegExp = new RegExp(
r"((https?:www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)?");
final urlMatches = urlRegExp.allMatches(response);
List<String> urls = urlMatches.map(
    (urlMatch) => text.substring(urlMatch.start, urlMatch.end))
.toList();
```

Now get last element from the list:

```
print(urls[urls.length-1]);
```