# How to convert this response to playlist

Tags: flutter, dart, vlc

How to convert this response to playlist in flutter

I'm using flutter_vlc_player

#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,METRO TV
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,TVONE
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/5

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,TVRI
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/33

Comment: Please post some code what you already tried and please clarify further what to Playlist means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use of the [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html) method would have solved your problem if you tried!!

**Code:**

```
void main() {
  String text = '''#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,METRO TV http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,TVONE http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/5

#EXTINF:0 tvg-logo="http://example.com/logo/" tvg-id="" ,TVRI http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/33''';

  text.split("\n").forEach((line) {
    var splits = line.split('http://');
    splits.length >= 3 ? print('http://' + splits[2]) : null;
  });
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/3
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/5
http://127.0.0.1:8000/live/test/test/33
```